# Command to list available webcam/video devices?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, video, webcam

Is there a way to list all webcams that are available to my Mac (e.g. FaceTime camera) using Terminal?

I know there's

```
diskutil list
```

to list all disks attached to my Mac, but is there a command that does the same thing for input cameras?

Things I've already tried:

```
system_profiler SPCameraDataType
```

This doesn't list the identifier with associated number, which is the information that I need from the list.

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
```

I tried this too, but I'm pretty sure this only works for Linux/Ubuntu, which I know nothing about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m curious what you’re planning to do with this list...

Comment: Listing hardware is not a crime, actually is a good practice for advanced users.

Comment: The answer may depend on what you actually want to do with the result. Listing all webcams can be accomplished with the command you've mentioned, but you seem to be looking for something else.

Answer (score 4):

Try `ioreg` command:

```
ioreg | grep -i cam
```

Comment: This only finds hardware cameras.

Comment: @nohillside wow, so you are saying that there are other camera that are not hardware?

Comment: No :-) But I can install software which allows me to use an iPhone or a DSLR as a webcam, without the iPhone or DSLR showing up as a camera in `ioreg`.

Comment: @nohillside show the command, :-)

Comment: Just install https://reincubate.com/camo/ and try yourself :-)

Comment: @elulcao there are virtual (software-based) cameras, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed webcamoid and Reincubate Camo, and both of their plugins are installed into

```
/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/
```

However Reincubate's [documentation](https://reincubate.com/support/camo/camo-faq/#compatibility) indicates that it is not compatible with FaceTime, so not all virtual cameras will work with it.